# MS Access Form Controls Will Only Move Together, but Not Grouped or Stacked

Tags: ms-access

I've been handed an access database that my company had a contractor build out for them more than a decade ago and asked to bring it up-to-date.  It's a relatively simple thing, generally within my limited MS Access skill, but I'm stumped by this:  Some of the controls on the forms have somehow been linked together such that they move together when I attempt to move one of the individuals.

The database was likely developed in Access 2007, but we're on 2016 currently.

The controls aren't grouped, at least so far as I can tell.  They don't select together (when I click on one, only its outline highlights, as opposed to grouped controls where when I click one, they all select).

They also don't appear to be stacked (although I have less experience with stacked layouts, which is to say none, but googling indicates that if they were stacked, they'd be surrounded by a dashed box).

The only clue is that when I click one of the controls, the other linked control has a small gray box appear in the upper left corner.

[image]

Hopefully this is something incredibly simple that I'll facepalm about after, but I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply a control with an associated label. Each can be moved independently by click and hold on the 'small grey box' and drag to desired location. Resize by click and drag on any of the anchor boxes.

The 'surrounded by a dashed box' would indicate a Layout Group. Layout can be removed by selecting controls and right click > Layout > Remove Layout. In my experience, selecting one control in a group does not select all, just reveals the group outlines. Once the group is revealed, all controls can be selected by clicking box with cross at upper left of group.

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping it would be something simple!

Comment: Don't break your nose with that facepalm!